# Korean symbols written ontop of each oher in Chromium

Tags: chromium, korean

I've got the really weird korean letters beeing written ontop of eachother, which is really disturbing as you can't read them anymore. In the picture you see what it looks and should look like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5RGN.jpg

The "one" symbol is actually that what you're able to see in the tooltip ...

Just installed my Ubuntu a few hours ago - hope to get this solved, as it only appears in Chromium, but not in the tooltips when hovering over things.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem, but it depends on the website. Facebook is the worst.

To help the problem, I went to setting > language, and installed the Korean language. Ubuntu still uses English for everything as a default, I just now have Korean language packs and fonts. Most websites work better with Korean fonts.